# How to get list data by condition in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

I have 1 question, it seems to be unresolved. Please allow me to rephrase the question. I am learning about Realtime Database in Xamarin. I have researched in the documentation, and successfully posted the data. My data structure is as follows:

[image]

This is how I display the list of data in real time:

**ListChat.xaml.cs**

```
public ObservableCollection<MyDatabaseRecord> DatabaseItems { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MyDatabaseRecord>();
public static string FirebaseClient = "xxxxxx";
public static string FrebaseSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
public FirebaseClient fc = new FirebaseClient(FirebaseClient,
               new FirebaseOptions { AuthTokenAsyncFactory = () => Task.FromResult(FrebaseSecret) });
               
protected void LoadListChat()
{
    BindingContext = this;
    string userid = "001";

    var FirebaseClient = fc
    .Child("RecordsChat")
    .AsObservable<MyDatabaseRecord>()
    .Subscribe((dbevent) =>
    {
        if (dbevent.Object != null)
        {                        
            DatabaseItems.Add(dbevent.Object);
        }
    });
}
```

**DetailChat.xaml.cs**

```
private void send_messenger_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string user1 = "001";//For example 
    string user2 = "002";//For example 

    var roomName = "room_" + user1 + '_' + user2;

    fc.Child("RecordsChat").Child(roomName).PostAsync(new MyDatabaseRecord
    {
        NameUser = lb_nameuser.Text,        
        Content = txt_messenger.Text,
        UID = user1,
        ViewUser = false,
        RoomID = roomName
    });

    txt_messenger.Text = "";
}
```

However as in my data structure above. How can I get a list of data by `room_` provided that `RoomID = userid`.

I know this may not be a new issue. However, I've tried everything and it still doesn't work. Any help please. Thanks

Comment: your previous question was closed as a duplicate, and many links were provided to similar questions.  Someone also left a lengthy comment suggesting a change in how you are storing your data.  Simply deleting that question and posting it again does not change anything.  Further, this is really just a Firebase query issue, it has nothing specific to do with Xamarin.

Comment: Yes, I deleted the duplicate question. Due to the unresolved issue, I had to re-post. Please get your help.

Comment: Instead of deleting and reposting the same problem, consider updating your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70336745/how-can-get-list-conditionally-child-firebase-realtime-database-in-xamarin) (instead of deleting it). If that question was not a duplicate of the ones I linked to it, we can reopen it based on additional information you provide without losing information and without duplicating effort.

Comment: Since the previous question was closed and asked to delete the duplicate question, I had to post a new question :(

Comment: I accidentally deleted it. Sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to filter the data after  `OnceAsync` method .

```
var lst = (await fc.Child("RecordsChat").Child(roomName).OnceAsync<MyDatabaseRecord>()).Select(x =>
new MyDatabaseRecord
{
   NameUser = x.Object.NameUser ,
   Content = x.Object.Content ,
   UID = x.Object.UID ,
   RoomID = x.Object.RoomID 
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you. Looks like you misunderstood me. As in my current structure above. I have 2 rooms: room_001_002 and room_001_003. It should only display 1 of those 2 rooms, if the condition is satisfied room_.... = userid. As in the example above I have userid="001". Should I get the list of room_, then split that string room_, if the userid is in that string then output the result?

Comment: In your example it would probably work fine if it were to get the detailed results of each room_

Comment: I saw you post another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70353102/how-to-get-last-child-data-firebase-realtime-database-and-show-in-xamarin) , did you solve this problem ? IF did  could you post the solution here and mark it as an answer ?