# How to get last-child data Firebase Realtime Database and show in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

I have a list of `room_` retrieved from Firebase Realtime Database. However:

1. How do I get the last-child data of each of those `room_`. Like the example in the image below: I want to get the result `Key: Mqof3FYCrNdn0ipU5T8` for `room_001_002`, `Key: MqofzCyjqQJ56BLiNHu` for `room_001_003` and display in CollectionView.

[image]

**ListRoom.xaml**

```
<CollectionView x:Name="listChats" ItemsSource="{Binding IteamGetRoomChats}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,0,0,2">
                <StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding IteamGetRoomChatsChild}">
                    <Frame x:Name="Tap_chatdetail" HasShadow="False" Padding="12,10" BackgroundColor="#f5f4f4">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Content}" FontSize="13"/>     
                        <Label Text="{Binding NameUser}" FontSize="13"/>        
                        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding viewdetailChat}" CommandParameter="{Binding RoomID}"  />
                        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>              
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

**ListRoom.xaml.cs**

```
public ObservableCollection<GetRoomChats> IteamGetRoomChats { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<GetRoomChats>();
public ObservableCollection<MyDatabaseRecord> IteamGetRoomChatsChild { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<MyDatabaseRecord>();

List<GetRoomChats> listroomuser = new List<GetRoomChats>();
....
public Command viewdetailChat { get; set; }
....
public ListRoom()
{
    LoadContentChat();
}
protected async void LoadContentChat()
{
    BindingContext = this;

    //Get room user success 
    var FirebaseClient = fc
        .Child("RecordsChat")
        .AsObservable<GetRoomChats>()
        .Subscribe((dbevent) =>
        {
            foreach (var room in listroomuser)
            {
                if (dbevent.Key == room.RoomID)
                {
                    IteamGetRoomChats.Add(dbevent.Object);
                }
            }

            //How to get the last column of each of those room_

        });
    //End get room user success
    
    viewdetailChat = new Command( async() => await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailChats(//get roomid)));
}
```

**Models**

```
public class GetRoomChats
{
    public string RoomID { get; set; }
}

public class MyDatabaseRecord
{
    public string UID { get; set; }
    public string NameUser { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string RoomID { get; set; }
}
```

2. How can I get the roomid to execute the Command without going through any ViewModel.

   ```
   viewdetailChat = new Command( async() => await Navigation.PushAsync(new DetailChats(//get roomid)));
   ```

Thanks for all the help. Thanks

**Update**

Questions 1:

```
var FirebaseClient = fc
    .Child("RecordsChat")
    .AsObservable<GetRoomChats>()
    .Subscribe((dbevent) =>
    {
        foreach (var room in listroomuser)
        {
            if (dbevent.Key == room.RoomID)
            {
                IteamGetRoomChats.Add(dbevent.Object);

                //Get last-child off room
                var query = fc.Child("RecordsChat").Child(dbevent.Key).OrderByKey().LimitToLast(1);
                var get = query.AsObservable<MyDatabaseRecord>().Subscribe((dbeventchild) =>
                {
                    IteamGetRoomChatsChild.Add(dbeventchild.Object);//get Null
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+last-child+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: for your 2nd question, you are already passing `RoomID` as a `CommandParameter`, but your command does not accept any parameters

Comment: I looked at the doc you submitted in question 1, I do the check and get the `LimitToLast` in `fc.Child("RecordsChat").Child(dbevent.Key)`, but only get `null` value, I was in the wrong place any. Looking forward to your guidance by answer. Thank you

Comment: How about using the method `addListenerForSingleValueEvent`  mentioned in that link?